# Why do the outputs of those apt invocations differ?

Tags: apt

When running `apt-get dist-upgrade` it shows, that there are zero packages that are *not* upgraded. When I run `apt-get autoremove` it informs me that there are two packages that can be upgraded. To me this is counter intuitive. There are actually two packages installed from *testing* that could be upgraded, but won't as there are some dependency problems.

I'm on Debian 8.6.

My question is: Why doesn't `apt-get dist-upgrade` tell me about those two packages, but `apt-get autoremove` does?

```
root@host ~# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@host ~# apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Comment: `not upgraded` is not the same as `could be upgraded`.

Comment: Something set   with apt-pinning  or packages set on hold?

Comment: @Bahamut Nothing held back, pinning exists, but nothing manually adjusted. How would pinning cause this?

Comment: I pinnt  2 package to a special Version and `apt-get autoremove`  complains in my case that I had brocken packages.

Comment: @Bahamut Unfortunately, for me, it isn't complaining at all.